# Difficult with foreach, sum and table (noob)

Tags: php, html

I have a table that is created by my billing manager. It has a `foreach` that inserts the calls in the table that list it, pretty simple.

I have as a task from my boss to include on the bottom of the table the sum of all call durations, which is an item from it, but doesn't appear as a sum.

After some hours, I surrendered to my ignorance. I *guess* the easiest way should be to put on this (resumed) section to include the value on an array:

---

```
foreach ($this->call_list as $id => $callsList): ?>

<td class="text-center"><?php echo $this->format->fmt_segundos(array("a" => $callsList['billsec'], "b" => 'hms')); ?></td>

<?php endforeach?>
```

---

And then, down here, I would put the code to sum all the values on that variable:

---

```
<td class="text-center"><?php echo $this->translate("Duration") ?> <?php echo "<br>"; ?>  <label class="label label-info"><?php echo $this->totals['tempo']; ?></label></td>
```

---

But I don't know how. Could you guys help me?

Comment: Started using array_push, but it says it needs to be a string... still trying.

Comment: Is it just a case of have a variable defined before the loop `$totalSec=0;` and then in the foreach having `$totalSec+=$callsList['billsec'];` and then put `$totalSec` in the totals (formatted as needed).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but i figured another way to do it. Found another item that had sum, and kinda copied it. =p

Anyway, thanks for passing by =)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know spanish but i assume that function, fmt_segundos returns duration in seconds. In this case, the following code should do the trick:

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <td>id</td><td>Duration</td>
   </thead>
<?php
   $TOTAL= 0;
   foreach ($this->call_list as $id => $callsList){ 
      $a = $this->format->fmt_segundos(array("a" => $callsList['billsec'], "b" => 'hms'));
      $TOTAL += $a;
      echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td class="text-center">'.$id.'</td>';
      echo '<td class="text-center">';
      echo gmdate("H:i:s", $a); 
      echo '</td>';
      echo '</tr>';
   }
?>
    <tfoot>
        <td>TOTAL</td><td><?=gmdate("H:i:s",$TOTAL)?></td>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```